# Не удается получить ссылку на загруженную в firebase картинку

Tags: java, android, firebase, storage

Доброго времени суток. Проблема заключается в том, что я в своем android-приложении загружаю на сервер firebase картинку следующим способом

```
/**
 * Upload image from Bitmap localImage to Firebase server
 */
public void loadImageToServer(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    localImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] dataBAOS = baos.toByteArray();

    /***************** UPLOADS THE PIC TO FIREBASE*****************/
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().
            getReferenceFromUrl("gs://*************.appspot.com/userImages/");

    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putBytes(dataBAOS);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),R.string.error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showLoading(false);
        }

    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            urlToImage = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
            // TODO Здесь отправляется ивент на создание аккаунте в Auth
            showLoading(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Файл-то загружается, однако при попытке получить ссылку (видимо), вылазит такой вот exception:

```
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqn: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
```

Папка userImages в firebase существует, правила стоят следующие:

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/******-******.appspot.com/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
              allow read, write;
        }
    }
}
```

И притом файл действительно появляется в БД!

Answer (score 1):

1) Кажется, вы пытаетесь сделать анонимную загрузку на сервер.
Но у вас есть неактуальный токен.
Попробуйте вызывать перед методом загрузки логаут:

```
.signOut();
```

2) Если же нет, вам не нужен анонимный доступ к загрузке файлов (а по умолчанию анонимный доступ действительно не нужен), то измените правила на вот такие, и попробуйте ещё раз:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/your_app.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Update:
Для того, чтобы отправлять картинку пользователя при регистрации пользователя нужно получить ID и дальше работать с этим ID. Это всё оформляется последовательно. Как только вернётся ответ, что пользователь зарегистрирован - отправляйте картинку по ID этого пользователя:

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (taskResult.isSuccessful()) {
                    //вызываем метод загрузки файла. Например, uploadImage();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential error: ", taskResult.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

После успешной загрузки в папку пользователя вы получите Url:

```
private void uploadImage() {
        //Prepare file
        String fileName = ... ; //ваш метод получения имени файла
        File file = ... ; //ваш метод получения файла        

        //prepare user
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userUid = user.getUid();

        //prepare storage
        StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl(BuildConfig.StorageReference);
        StorageReference fileRef = storage.child(userUid).child(fileName);


        //upload
        UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file));
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //ошибка загрузки     
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //успешная загрузка

                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type,
                // and download URL.
                Uri urlFile = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Мне при регистрации необходимо на сервер загружать картинку пользователя со смартфона. А за ответ спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста) Вы хотите одновременно с регистрацией это сделать?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: обновил ответ - добавил пример выгрузки файли при регистрации

Comment: Можно поподробней про ID, пожалуйста?) Как мы его получаем, если пользователь ещё не зарегистрирован? Будет ли этот ID сброшен при перезаходе в приложение? Или как? Спасибо

Comment: Как только пользователь зарегистрировался - у него есть ID. И тут же можно начинать выгружать картинку. Я это имел ввиду.